# How to handle hybrid devices in click/touch events properly?

Tags: javascript, angular, click, touch

I'm trying to find out how to work with hybrid devices when it comes to binding touch and click events, but I can't find any solution that actually seems to work (I haven't got a hybrid device so I cannot test directly but since the failed attempts doesn't even work on normal devices I assume they don't work on a hybrid device either).

The problem is that on a hybrid device you have to cover both touch and click events without firing the functions twice. So if you look at my failed attempts (2 and 3) you can see that I bind to both `touchend` and `click`, but there appears to be some sort of syntax error or something because this causes none of the events to actually fire.

The first solution works fine but that's when I'm just using one or the other of the event firing types.

What I've tried so far:

**1** - Works on touch devices and click devices:

```
_renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchend' : 'click', (e) => {

  console.log('works');  
});
```

**2** - Doesn't fire on either touch or click devices:

```
_renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'touchend click', (e) => {

  console.log('works');

  e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

**3** - Doesn't fire on either touch or click devices:

```
_renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'touchend, click', (e) => {

  console.log('works');  

  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

As you can see the first example covers 2/3 device types, while the other ones cover 0.

How can I make sure that my functions will run properly on every device?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a Subject and debounce for a couple of milliseconds so you only have one event, something like this:

```
import {Component, Renderer} from '@angular/core'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular2';
  subject = new Subject();
  
  constructor(renderer: Renderer) {
    renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'touchend', (e) => {
      console.log('touchend');
      this.subject.next(e);
    });
    renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (e) => {
      console.log('click');
      this.subject.next(e);
    });

    this.subject.debounceTime(100).subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event); //do stuff here
    })
  }
}
```

So when you use hybrid devices, you will get this:
[image]

Two events were fired, but you only get one on your Observable.

You can play around in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xupKhrgk8iCjmvyWV07S?p=preview)

Comment: I'm intrigued, I will check this out more thoroughly.

Answer (score 6):

Just add (tap) directive instead of (click) directive on your components and add hammerjs to your index.html file.

Angular 2 will do all the job for you.

Example:

```
<my-component (tap)="doSomething()"></my-component>
```

On your index.html add:

```
<script src="hammer.min.js"></script>
```

To get hammerjs

```
npm install hammerjs --save
```

With this the click and the tap will work fine.
If you want to have more control over the tap or you want to bind events to your element on runtime try something like this.

```
_hammerEvents: HammerManager;

public bindTapEvent(element: ElementRef):void{
    this._hammerEvents = new Hammer(element.nativeElement);
    this._hammerEvents.on("tap", (event:any) => { /* do something */});
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why I need hammerjs?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Angular 2 already has a directive (tap) that was provided for this cases, this directive responds to tap event (ontouchstart, touchend) and will work with click events. Under the hood Angular 2 will check if hammerjs was loaded.

Comment: Do you know how to bind a tap to the document? I get an error saying it's not implemented

Comment: Thanks @dlcardozo. It works like a charm. I tested on desktop, adnroid phone as well as iPad with iOS 12.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  Works awesomely for Angular and was the missing knowledge I needed.